# Is it correct to say Win-win lottery?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Is it correct to say Win-win lottery? It is meant the kind of lottery where you will get a prize anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Win-win usually means a situation in which every person involved benefits.

A lottery that paid out more than the ticket price to every purchaser would be very unusual. Enough lottery operators have heard of how [Voltaire](https://www.laphamsquarterly.org/luck/voltaires-luck) became wealthy that such things are rare these days. And the lottery operators are unlikely to view themselves as benefiting.

So I'm going to presume you mean that everybody gets at least a *small* prize. Probably that should have a more descriptive name such as "lottery with consolation prizes" or some such thing.